# Fórmula Excel Lista Personalizada

Tags: microsoft-excel

Olá,

Estou criando uma planilha e estou com um problema.
Imagine que está ocorrendo um torneio.
Para controlar este torneio eu tenho várias abas, Janeiro, Fevereiro, Março, etc..
Dentro de cada aba eu tenho os nomes dos participantes do torneio, e quantos pontos eles fizeram ao longo daquele mês.
Nem todos os jogadores participam do torneio todos os meses.

Na planilha Janeiro eu tenho:
Anderson - 10
André - 14
Bruno - 15

Na planilha fevereiro eu tenho:
Anderson - 12
Bruno - 9
Carlos - 15

Na planilha Março eu tenho:
Anderson - 8
Carlos - 10
Daniel - 12

O que eu gostaria de fazer é, ao final de todas as abas referente a todos os meses, criar uma aba "Total" e reunir o nome de todos os participantes.
Neste caso:
Anderson, André, Bruno, Carlos e Daniel

Somando-se todos seus respectivos pontos.
Neste caso:
Anderson - 30
Carlos - 25
Bruno - 24
André - 14
Daniel - 12

Pelo que li sobre, preciso de uma fórmula matricial que fizesse isso, para varrer a planilha dos meses, buscando os nomes e somando-se seus pontos.
mas não encontrei nada aproximado com minhas necessidades e não consegui fazer por conta própria.

Alguém conseguiria me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na última folha (chamada, por exemplo, de "Total"), crie uma coluna para cada mês, mantendo na primeira coluna os nomes dos participantes. Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, em cada célula dos meses, use a seguinte fórmula e trocando o nome do mês conforme o título das folhas dos meses (como ela usa o `$` pra fixar endereços que não devem mudar, você pode fazer para a linha do primeiro nome e depois copiar essas células para os demais nomes):

```
=SEERRO(PROCV($A1;Janeiro!$A$1:$B$3;2;FALSO);0)
```

Essa fórmula irá procurar (por meio da função `PROCV`) o nome da coluna A da folha "Total" na coluna A da folha dada ("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", etc) e devolver o valor da coluna B (a pontuação). Se não encontrar, ela devolve 0 (garantido pelo uso da função `SEERRO`). O parâmetro `FALSO` serve pra indicar que a busca tem de ser *exata*.

Bom, tendo os valores nas colunas, é só somá-los numa coluna "Total" (com a fórmula `=SOMA(B2:D2)`, por exemplo). Se você não quiser ver as colunas dos meses nessa última folha, é só escondê-las (selecione as colunas pelo cabeçalho, clique com o botão direito do mouse e selecione "Ocultar").

O exemplo que eu fiz só com três meses [está disponível no 4shared](http://www.4shared.com/file/a262_dgWce/TesteSOPT.html).

Comment: Luiz, excelente resposta. 
Só tenho uma dúvida, eu dei um exemplo com 3 participantes por mês, mas na verdade eu tenho cerca de 100 a 150 participantes por mês, onde alguns participam todos os meses, outros participam mês ou outro, e outros participam uma única vez e não voltam.
Há uma forma de retirar automaticamente todos os nomes do mês de Janeiro, juntar com todos os nomes de Fevereiro, juntar com todos os nomes de Março e assim ele criar a lista de nomes automaticamente na aba total?
Com essa lista de nomes eu aplicaria o PROCV que vc me sugeriu.

Comment: Assim de cabeça eu não sei (preciso pensar um pouco), mas deve ser possível criar uma lista única de nomes a partir da junção de várias folhas *usando somente fórmulas* (já que me parece ser a sua intenção evitar VBA...). Mas eu sugiro que você abra uma pergunta específica para isso.

Comment: OK, Obrigado Luiz.